# Convert List to Array error

Tags: c#, arrays, list, xamarin

I am trying to Convert a List to an Array to add to my ArrayAdapter, but when I am trying to do that I get the error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[]' to 'string[]'"

This is my code:

```
List<ClassName> Names = new List<ClassName>();

foreach (var property in coinPropery)
{
    var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Names>>(property.ToString());
    coins.AddRange(propertyList);
    Console.WriteLine(Names);
}

string[] NamesArray = Names.InArray();
```

The code in my ClassName is:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Names is string, but list

Comment: I want to get an Array of all Names

Comment: To add an ArrayAdapter to add to a listview

Comment: `InArray` is not a method on `List<T>` - unless youve written it - and in which case we need the code of that extension method. Also you use a class/struct `Names` but I dont see that anywhere in your question either.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop doesn't do anything interesting.. and your call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` will most likely throw an error, since you can't use a variable like a class.  I get renaming things for the public.. but you better make sure you haven't introduced errors due to that renaming.

Comment: Is it intentional here that Names will never contain any entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to do ToArray() instead of InArray()

Your problem is you are assigning an array of ClassName to an array of string

You can try:

```
string[] NamesArray = Names.Select(c=>c.Name).ToArray();
```